# prompt user to input files in python

Tags: python

I have a python script that takes two files as arguments and runs. Is there any way to prompt user to input file?  I have seen `fileinput` method, but is there any way to describe two files seperately?

Comment: This question is very unclear. What is the expected input and expected output?

Comment: Do you want your python script to actually load the files ?

Comment: i need something similar to raw_input that load files and than the code will go :

Comment: for line in file1:
.....
for line in file2:
....
instead of defining files i want the user to input them

Comment: what do you want to do with the files? what do they contain? can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: the files contains probabilities in each line. i want to process each line transform probabilities to log, and calculate the ratio of two file.  the only problem is that i will be doing this on more files, so instead of changing the names each time, i am wondering if there is any ways to give files as arguments

Answer (score 2):

i think i understand you better now.

```
import os

file1 = input("please type the directory path for file 1:\n")
file2 = input("please type the directory path for file 2:\n")

def convert_to_log(afloat):
    converted_number = # whatever the conversion equation is. Variable afloat appears here
    return converted_number

def load_probabilities(file_in):
    prob_list = []
    with open(file_in, 'r') as f1:
        for line in f1:
            try:
                prob_list.append(convert_to_log(float(line)))
            except:
                continue
    return prob_list

prob_file1 = load_probabilities(file1)
prob_file2 = load_probabilities(file2)

ratio = list(map(lambda x,y: x/y, a,b)) #calculates probability ratios

print(ratio)
```

So we have a function that is in charge of the loading the file and storing the probabilities in a list (load_probabilities) and another function that convert the probabilities to logarithmic (convert_to_log) just before the values get appended. Will this work?

Comment: Don't forget to use os.path.abspath(path) on what's returned.

Comment: That code does not load files. It is similar to raw_input()